# xslt parameter passing issue -- <xsl:text> returning empty result

Tags: c#, xslt

Below is my code and i am passing Xslt argument & checking if argument is true then xslt:text should return,but i am not geting any value.Well i am new for xslt.

```
    string filename = "tmp.xml";
    string stylesheet = "result.xslt";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create the XslTransform and load the stylesheet.
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(stylesheet);

        //Load the XML data file.
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(filename);
        XsltArgumentList obj = new XsltArgumentList();
        bool category = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Code"].Contains("Software");
        obj.AddParam("category", "", category);
        //Create an XmlTextWriter to output to the console.             
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        //Transform the file.
        xslt.Transform(doc, obj, writer, null);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

-----  result.xslt file ----

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
  <xsl:param name="category" />
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:if test="$category=true">
      <xsl:text>Software is avilable.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

------ tmp.xml file -------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<data>
  <circle>
    <radius>12</radius>
  </circle>
  <circle>
    <radius>37.5</radius>
  </circle>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

`test="$category=true"` means `test="$category = child::true"`, and unless you have an element named "true", the result of the comparison will be false. I guess you meant `test="$category=true()"`, though it's simpler to write `test="$category"`.

(I'm not that familiar with the .NET transformation API, but I assume that when AddParam() supplies a boolean value, what the stylesheet sees is also a boolean).